# SQL Server 2008 express installation with Wix 3.5

Tags: sql-server-2008, wix, wix3.5

i trying to install sql server 2008 using wix3.5 
i tried the below link to install .Net framework 3.5 and 4.0 its working fine.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm

```
<BootstrapperFile Include="SQL Server 2008 Express">
    <ProductName>SQL Server 2008</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
```

same way i trying for using the sql server 2008 installation using above code, but its not working, any idea where i done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server 2008 Express you need to include `Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.10.0"`:

```
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.10.0">
    <ProductName>SQL Server 2008</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
```

**Note:** My example came from my installation using Visual Studio 2010 (Windows SDK 7.0a).  The include is likely `Microsoft.Sql.Server.Express.9.2` for VS 2008, but I have no way of verifying this right now.